Brew on M3 Mac with Sequoia thinks the right Ruby is the El Capitan/Intel one
Upgraded a Mac from an Intel model to an M3 (ARM) one, migrated the files and settings. The ARM Mac is running Sequoia (15.1.1) As it always happens, the migrated Homebrew packages and brew itself were immediately broken, on account of having Intel executables instead of ARM ones.
I've reinstalled Homebrew from scratch via the official curl/execute method. So brew is an ARM binary now. However, any command (even brew config) tries to upgrade ruby to 3.3.6 - and while doing so, somehow picks up the Intel build. The messages go:
seva@Mac ~ % brew config
 => Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-ruby/blobs/sha256:720d4fb1164e600f787d656019a8e46314dc38e1885f4a8df809c180acf5e7b3
 .Already downloaded: /Users/seva/Library/Caches/Homebrew/portable-ruby-3.3.6.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
 ==> Pouring portable-ruby-3.3.6.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/vendor-install.sh: line 259: ./3.3.6/bin/ruby: Bad CPU type in executable
Error: Failed to install ruby 3.3.6!
Error: Failed to upgrade Homebrew Portable Ruby!

Brew update/upgrade/install/uninstall anything give the same error.
I've looked inside portable-ruby-3.3.6.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz - it contains an Intel build of ruby. Frustratingly, in the same folder under Caches there is portable-ruby-3.3.6.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz - and that one contains an ARM build. Tried installing it directly - same error. Tried renaming it to match the El Capitan archive - got a checksum mismatch error.
Why would brew pick the Intel build of ruby as the latest?
Rosetta 2 is not installed, and I'd rather not go there.

You now have a mixed Intel/ARM Homebrew setup, which will end in tears (ask me how I know). I would suggest either uninstalling the Intel version entirely, or to use a completely different base path (like /opt) for the ARM version.

There is already an /opt/homebrew with bin/brew in it. It's just that the brew command defaults to /usr/local/bin/brew which is a symlink to ../Homebrew/bin/brew.

It's your shell that defaults to picking /usr/local/bin/brew, you need to change $PATH so that /opt/homebrew/bin gets precedence.
